# Using Pandas in Python to rename columns across multiple sheets (XLS)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets, rename

I have an excel file (.xls) where I have headers across multiple sheets that I would like to rename using pandas then re save the document. This is what I am currently trying:

```
def read_File():
   file = 'TheFile.xls'
   xls = pd.read_excel(file)
   xls.rename(columns = {'aa': 'A','Aa':'A', 'bb':'B'}, inplace =True)
   xls.to_excel(file, index = False)
```

I think this is working partially, but the file that is saved has only retained the first worksheet, how do I get this working for the whole workbook?

I'm not sure if I have missed something obvious and there is a much simpler way of achieving what I want, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Pandas documentation for the [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) method, you can specify `sheet_name = None` and get back a dictionnary of dataframes (one for each sheet).

You could try like this:

```py
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def read_File():
    file = "TheFile.xls"
    sheets = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
    with ExcelWriter(file) as writer:
        for name, sheet in sheets.items():
            sheet.rename(columns={"aa": "A", "Aa": "A", "bb": "B"}, inplace=True)
            sheet.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name=name, index=False)
        writer.save()
```